# Index of a character in a string

Tags: python

I am trying to find out the index of a specific character in a string.For example:

```
MyString:abfkjgck
Text:afgf
```

I want to find the index of each character of text in MyString.This is what  have tried:

```
a=string.ascii_uppercase
t=input("Enter the plain text :")
d=t[0]
x=a.index(d)
print(x)
```

I keep getting a Value error.

Comment: If You are using python 2, use `raw_input` instead of `input`. The other issue is you are trying to find index in ascii_uppercase, and the input string is all lowercase.

Comment: I am using Python 3.x.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
a=string.ascii_uppercase
t=input("Enter the plain text :")
x=[a.index(d.upper()) for d in t]
print(x)
```

Sample output:

```
Enter the plain text :afgf
[0, 5, 6, 5]
```

#### Discussion:

Consider why this code can generate a `ValueError`:

```
a=string.ascii_uppercase
t=input("Enter the plain text :")
d=t[0]
x=a.index(d)
print(x)
```

A `ValueError` occurs if `d` is not found in `a`.  Note that `s` consists only of upper case ASCII letters.  Consequently, it does not contain any lower case letters.  If the user enters a lower case letter, a `ValueError` message will result.

This was eliminated in the suggested code above by using `d.upper()` in place of just `d`.

Also, to gather the indices of all the characters typed by the user instead of just the first, a *list comprehension* can be used: `x=[a.index(d.upper()) for d in t]`.

#### Ignoring spaces

Suppose that we want to ignore any spaces that the user enters:

```
import string
a=string.ascii_uppercase
t=input("Enter the plain text :")
x=[a.index(d.upper()) for d in t if d != " "]
print(x)
```

#### Gracefully handling non-alphabetic characters

In this code, any space or other non-alphabetic character is assigned the value of `-1`:

```
import string
a=string.ascii_uppercase
t=input("Enter the plain text :")
x=[a.find(d.upper()) for d in t]
print(x)
```

Example:

```
Enter the plain text :a#b% c
[0, -1, 1, -1, -1, 2]
```

Comment: What if the t string contains spaces?

Comment: @lavish What would you like to have happen if the `t` string contains spaces?  Would you like to have them ignored? Or, assigned some value, such as -1?

Comment: I would like them to be removed.So i should be using t.replace(" ","") right?

Comment: @lavish Yes, that would work fine.  It happens that the solution that I just added to the answer uses a different approach.